# How do I create a neat table-like layout in a basic text-only program?

Tags: java

The program needs to have titles like Name, Age, and Height. Underneath, the user will enter names, ages, and heights, which need to stay in-line, as though they are in invisible columns.
eg.

```
Name------------------Age-----Height

Gus Smith------------22-------5"11

Hank Mathewson---42--------6"1

Frank Dimitrianus---54-------5"6
```

Instead of dashes, empty space though.

I have everything else done, I just need some kind of command to have entries automatically take up a certain amount of space. Gus Smith needs to take up 20 characters of space, and Frank Dimitrianus needs to take up 20 characters of space, so that the ages will start in the correct position, in-line with each other.

Thanks

Comment: You can check the number of characters in the name, and subtract that from the total space you want the name section to take up. Say you want 30 characters for the name slot, print out the name and (30- name.length()) spaces.

Answer (score 3):

See http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/java_formatted_strings.html.

It has (way) more examples than I can think off the top of my head.

Answer (score 3):

`String.format` can be used to space pad fields:

```
String formattedString = String.format("%-20s %-5s %-7s", name, age, height)
```

Assuming you have all your fields as strings. `-20` is a minimum size of the column, so if you have names longer then 20 characters you may need to truncate the fields that are too long or resize your name padding based on the longest field. So you may want to construct the format based on the longest string:

```
String formatForSize(int maxLength) {
  return "%-" + maxLength + "%-5s %-7s";
}
```

and you have some output loop:

```
String format = formatForSize(maxNameSize); //invarient
for (Person person : people ) {
  String personString = String.format(format, person.getName(), person.getAge(), person.getHeight);
  ...
}
```

The size of the max name can come from the input method: however the values for the table are read in.

Answer (score 1):

[String.format()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) is the way to go. It takes as its first parameter a *format string* that makes use of format specifiers to specify the data type and other flags to control text-alignment, precision etc.

Here's a simple table implementation to get you started.

*User class:*

```
public class User {
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private float height;

    public User(String name, int age, float height) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.height = height;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%-20s | %5d | %5.2f", name, age, height);
    }

    private static String getTableHeader() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(String.format(
                               "%-20s | %5s | %5s", "Name", "Age", "Height"));
        char[] line = new char[sb.length()];
        Arrays.fill(line, '-');
        return sb.append("\n").append(new String(line)).toString();
    }

public static void printUserTable(ArrayList<User> users) {
    System.out.println(getTableHeader());
    for (User user : users) {
        System.out.println(user);
    }
}
}
```

*Main program*

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();

    users.add(new User("Gus Smith", 22, 5.11f));
    users.add(new User("Hank Mathewson", 42, 6.1f));
    users.add(new User("Frank Dimitrianus", 54, 5.6f));

    User.printUserTable(users);
}
```

*Output*

```
Name                 |   Age | Height
-------------------------------------
Gus Smith            |    22 |  5.11
Hank Mathewson       |    42 |  6.10
Frank Dimitrianus    |    54 |  5.60
```

I think you can take up from here. Should probably start by getting the heights to print as `5'11"`.

Comment: +1, I liked the information provided :-), though I have to wait for the next day to upvote, since my limit is gone for the day :(

Comment: @nIcEcOw, I'd hold you onto your word. Maybe send a reminder too :)

Comment: LOL :-) no need, that is why I posted the comment, so that I can check that out tomorrow, from my activity tab. Else will loose the link :-) Though send me a reminder, I will upvote thrice :-)

Comment: You really are a nice cow! /jk :D

Comment: @nIcEcOw Man of his word! Thanks, and I see you're from CHD. My home town is just two hours away.. LDH :) See, I'm smiling!

Comment: Ahha, so you are from Ludhiana, good. Happy to know someone living closer to my place on stackoverflow :-) So you settled in Mumbai ?

Comment: Yeah, I have a job here. Visit home at holidays and festivals.